# How to start Chrome browser with kivy-iOS

Tags: python, ios, google-chrome, kivy

Platform dependency issue.

In the following code, *webbrowser.get("chrome")* runs with no issue on Mac. And on Windows, it runs OK if full path is specified, *webbrowser.get("C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s")*.

But in the case of iPhone,

- *webbrowser.get("chrome")* returns None. Useless.
- Chrome's full path is */var/containers/Bundle/Application/<uuid>/Chrome.app*? (I could not find it. *glob.glob* returns nothing in */var/containers* or in */Applications*!)

How can I start Chrome? Any advice would be highly appreciated!

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import webbrowser
from kivy.lang import Builder

class MyButton(Button):
    def button_clicked(self):
        wb = webbrowser.get("chrome")
        wb.open("https://www.google.com")

Builder.load_string("""
MyButton:
<MyButton>:
    text:'Click to open google site.'
    on_release:self.button_clicked()
""")

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyButton()

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that an iPhone even has a copy of Chrome.  It's much less common on phones than on computers.  Most users just use Safari.

Comment: The behavior of oauth2client is different between Chrome and Safari, and Chrome one is smoother. So if Chrome is found, I want the users to use it.